# Not able to display the Next activity when the button is clicked [Android]

Tags: android, button

I've been trying to get my button's to work for a very long time now, the funny thing is they I've implemented exactly the code exactly the same way for other buttons and they work fine, the buttons are not even throwing an errors or exceptions, and I'm getting tired.. I've tried pretty much everything I can think of but it still is not working.

The code for the activity where the buttons aren't working.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Button easy, medium, hard;

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exam_level_options);

    easy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.easyExamButn);
    medium = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mediumExamButn);
    hard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hardExamButn);

    easy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent (ExamOptionPage.this, EasyExam.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    medium.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent (ExamOptionPage.this, MediumExam.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    hard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent (ExamOptionPage.this, HardExam.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

/*@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()){ 

    case R.id.easyExamButn: 
        intent = new Intent(this, EasyExam.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, 0);
        break;

    case R.id.mediumExamButn:
        intent = new Intent(this, MediumExam.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, 0);
        break;

    case R.id.hardExamButn:
        intent = new Intent(this, HardExam.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, 0);
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

}*/
```

I've block commented out the switch statement, but and tried the other method still not luck, however the switch statement works for other activities. Doing exactly the same thing.

The log:

```
01-08 23:42:39.436: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.gc02.android.activities.OPTIONACTIVITY cmp=com.gc02.android/.activities.OptionActivity }
01-08 23:42:39.464: INFO/WindowManager(58): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
01-08 23:42:39.514: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34}
01-08 23:42:40.035: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.gc02.android/.activities.OptionActivity: 576 ms (total 576 ms)
01-08 23:42:41.234: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.gc02.android/.activities.ExamActivity }
01-08 23:42:41.614: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.gc02.android/.activities.ExamActivity: 358 ms (total 358 ms)
01-08 23:42:42.144: DEBUG/dalvikvm(58): GC freed 1726 objects / 84336 bytes in 104ms
01-08 23:42:43.474: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(1638): No keyboard for id 0
01-08 23:42:43.484: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(1638): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-08 23:42:46.694: DEBUG/dalvikvm(101): GC freed 551 objects / 26640 bytes in 75ms
01-08 23:42:47.584: DEBUG/dalvikvm(96): GC freed 411 objects / 22256 bytes in 116ms
01-08 23:42:48.054: DEBUG/dalvikvm(96): GC freed 719 objects / 53216 bytes in 166ms
01-08 23:42:51.114: DEBUG/dalvikvm(96): GC freed 693 objects / 42344 bytes in 70ms
01-08 23:42:59.134: INFO/NotificationService(58): enqueueToast pkg=com.gc02.android callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@44c476a8 duration=0
01-08 23:43:01.688: DEBUG/dalvikvm(99): GC freed 12471 objects / 573368 bytes in 1422ms
01-08 23:43:03.124: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c870a0
```

It would seem that the buttons are not being called, when I click them, what can I do?

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Make sure that the onClick methods are being called. Call `Log.i()` and print out some diagnostic info.

Comment: You may want to look at your layout, if somehow you're drawing over the top of the buttons, the onclick may not get fired.

Comment: You could also try in the xml saying `android:onclick="startEasy"` and adding a public method `startEasy` to your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Add below line after the pass id of the object lines, for calling onClick method in your java file:-

```
easy.setOnClickListener(this);
medium.setOnClickListener(this);
hard.setOnClickListener(this);


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==easy){
        intent = new Intent (ExamOptionPage.this, EasyExam.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if(v==medium){
        intent = new Intent (ExamOptionPage.this, MediumExam.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if(v==hard){
        intent = new Intent (ExamOptionPage.this, HardExam.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried doing it that way, but I still it doesn't go into the next activity

Comment: Thanks.. I also realised I was doing setContentView in another activity rather than startIntent

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your "intent" object defined anywhere. Infact, this should give a compilation error.

If you missed out the line here, then make sure you have included all of your activities in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I defined the intent, before the OnCreate Method, I've also added this into Manifest, but yet it still isn't working.